# JComboBox, many visible Items in list, but the first item is always selected

Tags: java, swing, events, jbutton, jcombobox

First i have these declared as global variables:

```
private static ArrayList<Resource> resourceList;    
private static JComboBox resourceBox;
```

Then i have a method that adds `String` items to a `JComboBox`. The `JComboBox` is put on a `JPanel` (not shown here).

```
private static JComboBox createComboBox(){
    resourceBox = new JComboBox();
    for(Resource r : resourceList){
        resourceBox.addItem(r.getName());
    }       
    return resourceBox;
}
```

The following method creates a `JButton` which is added to the same panel.

```
private static JButton createButton() {
    JButton b = new JButton("Click");       
    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.out.println(resourceBox.getSelectedItem());                
        }
    });
    return b;
}
```

It all displays nicely in my `JFrame` window. I can click the `JComboBox` and see all the different items in it. They're called "Res1", "Res2", "Res3" and so on. However, when i click the button it always prints "Res1" (first item in the list), no matter what I have selected in the combo box.

Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: `resourceBox` v. `resourcesBox`?

Comment: My fault when writing the code here. They all say resourceBox in my code but still wont work. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: @Goatcat Show us the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: One instance shadowing another?